# Counting different values using Data.Map leaks memory

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, dictionary, io

The following program uses 100+ MB RAM when counting different line lengths in a 250 MB file. How do I fix it to use less RAM? I suppose I misused lazy IO, `foldr` and laziness of `Data.Map` in values.

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List

main = do
  content <- readFile "output.csv"
  print $ (foldr count M.empty . map length . lines) content

count a b = M.insertWith (+) a 1 b
```

Comment: You can try to import Data.Map.Strict instead of Data.Map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first big mistake in

```
main = do
  content <- readFile "output.csv"
  print $ (foldr count M.empty . map length . lines) content

count a b = M.insertWith (+) a 1 b
```

is using `foldr`. That constructs an expression of the form

```
length firstLine `count` length secondLine `count` ... `count` length lastLine `count` M.empty
```

traversing the entire list of lines constructing the thunk - at that time not even evaluating the `length` calls due to laziness - before it is then evaluated right to left. So the entire file contents is in memory in addition to the thunk for building the `Map`.

If you build up a map from a list of things, **always** use a strict left fold (well, if the list is short, and the things not huge, it doesn't matter) unless the semantics require a right fold (if you're combining values using a non-commutative function, that might be the case, but even then it is often preferable to use a left fold and `reverse` the list before building the map).

`Data.Map`s (or `Data.IntMap`s) are spine-strict, that alone makes it impossible to generate partial output before the entire list has been traversed, so the strengths of `foldr` cannot be used here.

The next (possible) problem is (again laziness) that you don't evaluate the mapped-to values when putting them in the `Map`, so if there is a line length that occurs particularly often, that value becomes a huge thunk

```
((...((1+1)+1)...+1)+1)
```

Make it

```
main = do
  content <- readFile "output.csv"
  print $ (foldl' count M.empty . map length . lines) content

count mp a = M.insertWith' (+) a 1 mp
```

so that the lines can be garbage collected as soon as they have been read in, and no thunks can build up in the values. That way you never need more than one line of the file in memory at once, and even that need not be in memory entirely, since the `length` is evaluated before it is recorded in the `Map`.

If your `containers` package is recent enough, you could also

```
import Data.Map.Strict
```

and leave `count` using `insertWith` (without prime, the `Data.Map.Strict` module always evaluates values put into the map).

Comment: Thank you. With `Data.Map.Strict` or with `insertWith'` I get the desired memory behaviour. But now it is slower than Perl. Should I use ST [hashtables](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) ?

Comment: "But now it is slower" <- Hmm, the left fold shouldn't be slower than the right fold here, that's a bit surprising. Anyway, you should try `Data.IntMap.Strict`, that brings only minimal code changes, and should be faster for `Int` keys. Whether `hashtables` would perform better, I have no idea, try it out. If the range of line lengths isn't too large, a plain `STUArray` would be the fastest option, I think.

Comment: This is a minimal example I could make. I need something like `awk { print $5 $25 } | sort -c` in the end, so `IntMap` will not work for my full program. It didn't slow down after changing to left fold, I just expected it to become faster than equivalent Perl program and was disappointed.

Comment: I have no idea what `awk { print $5 $25 }` does. [Well, it prints something, that much is clear ;)] One thing that slows it down is of course that you read in the file as a linked list of `Char`s, that means the bytes must be decoded, a linked list built and deconstructed, ... If the file is all ASCII, `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` would be your best friend for speed. If it isn't, `Data.Text.IO` might be worth a try.

Comment: I only need ASCII so I tried bytestrings with conduits. Same story, so I suppose something is wrong with `Data.Map`.

Comment: Of course a `Data.Map.insertWith'` is `O(log size)`, so it could be that the `Map` is just too slow (what was the reason that `IntMap` doesn't work? Its inserts are of course `O(log size)` too, but generally faster than `Map`'s). Besides the mentioned `hashtables`, you could also look at [`unordered-containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers).

Comment: IntMap doesn't work because I need to count strings, or better tuples of strings.

Comment: So your keys are actually something like `(Int,String)` or what?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21657/discussion-between-nponeccop-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 0):

One way to get max residency down is to use `IntMap` instead of `Map`, which is a specialized version of the `Map` data structure for `Int` keys. It's a simple change:

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.IntMap as I
import Data.List

main = do
  content <- readFile "output.csv"
  print $ (foldr count I.empty . map length . lines) content

count a b = I.insertWith (+) a 1 b
```

Comparing this version against yours using `/usr/share/dict/words` saw max residency go from about 100MB to 60MB. Note that this was also without any optimization flags. If you crank those, max residency will very likely see further improvement.

Comment: I want O(1) space complexity

Comment: That isn't even possible.  You need at least memory linear in the number of distinct line lengths.

Comment: Everything is O(1) given upper bounds. It is useless to assume such case.

Comment: I assume the most common case - upper bounds on line lengths but not on line count. I don't think the issue worth arguing - it is common to say binary search has O(log N) complexity despite every comparison can depend on item size in arbitrary way.